# NFS share in Ubuntu core?

Tags: ubuntu-core, nfs

Is it possible to mount an NFS share in a raspberry pi running Ubuntu core? If so, how? Ideally, I would like the mounting to happen at boot and to do it in a place that a snap app can read and write to.

Comment: You have tried fstab right ? ( you will also need to install nfs-common) If you tried this and it didn't work you can also try using pam_mount. Let me know what you have tried and I'll get back to you with more details too

Comment: How do you install `nfs-common` in ubuntu core? There is no snap for it https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=nfs-common

Comment: @OskarL Ubuntu Core is quite different, you are not supposed to edit fstab there. Plus there are no mount.* available and also apt is not available, all is done via snaps.
Ignacio I am trying to solve the same issue and so far I found nothing. Have you found anything in the meantime?

Comment: Hi @Ignacio, I have the same issue today with Ubuntu Core 22. Did you find a solution to mount NFS share ?

Comment: Nope, I was never able to figure this out.